# Execute PHP code via javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, execute

I'm trying to connect to my SQL server via Javascript.
In order to do this, I have to execute some PHP code, but I'm having some trouble with that.

At the moment I use this code to execute a PHP script, without success

```
function testConnection()
{
    $.get("script/SQL/testConnection.php");
}
```

How is it possible to execute some PHP code, or connect to the server and execute SQL queries?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: From what environment, a web browser?

Comment: You cannot connect directly from Javascript to MySQL\* (unless you want to expose your entire database to the public internet). Javascript talks to PHP talks to MySQL. (\* meaning in the context of Javascript === browser)

Comment: So how do you tell that your script does not succeed?

Comment: I think u can use .load in juqery to load the php code

Comment: Javascript: `Hey PHP script do me a favor and look something up for me while I wait asynchronously`, PHP script: `Alright here are your results`, Javascript: `Thanks, now my wait is over and I can finally do something with the data in the callback`. That's how it works fundamentally.

Comment: Since everybody is suggesting I should take a look at the duplicate I will. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That `$.get` call you have is a relative URL. Let's say your user is on page `domain.com/home/`. If you use that code block, the user's browser is going to make a GET request to `domain.com/home/script/SQL/testConnection.php`. Is that what you are expecting?

What HTTP status code are you receiving back?